# Daterangepicker is not working in Web Pages ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am having problems with the daterangepicker script that I got from the adminlte.io template that cannot run on MVC web pages.

If I can run it in PHP, once I switch to asp.net MVC it won't work

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>MVC</title>
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- daterange picker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css');?>">
    <!-- bootstrap datepicker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css');?>">
    <!-- Bootstrap time Picker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/plugins/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css');?>">
    <!-- Select2 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/bower_components/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css');?>">
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/css/skins/skin-black.css">
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/plugins/iCheck/square/blue.css');?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css');?>">
    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
</head>
<body class="fixed hold-transition skin-black sidebar-mini">
  ...
  <div class="content-wrapper">
            <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
            @RenderBody()
          
            <!-- /.content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
        <!-- Main Footer -->
        <footer class="main-footer">
            <!-- Default to the left -->
            <strong>Copyright © 2019 <a href="#">Testing</a>.</strong> All rights reserved.
        </footer>
    </div>
    <!-- ./wrapper -->
    <!-- REQUIRED JS SCRIPTS -->
    <!-- jQuery 3 -->
    <script src="~/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
    <script src="~/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Select2 -->
    <script src="~/bower_components/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
    <!-- InputMask -->
    <script src="~/plugins/input-mask/jquery.inputmask.js');?>"></script>
    <script src="~/plugins/input-mask/jquery.inputmask.date.extensions.js');?>"></script>
    <script src="~/plugins/input-mask/jquery.inputmask.extensions.js');?>"></script>
    <!-- date-range-picker -->
    <script src="~/bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js');?>"></script>
    <script src="~/bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js');?>"></script>
    <!-- bootstrap datepicker -->
    <script src="~/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js');?>"></script>
    <!-- SlimScroll -->
    <script src="~/bower_components/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
    <!-- iCheck 1.0.1 -->
    <script src="~/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FastClick -->
    <script src="~/bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="~/dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            //Initialize Select2 Elements
            $('.select2').select2()

            //Datemask dd/mm/yyyy
            $('#datemask').inputmask('dd/mm/yyyy', { 'placeholder': 'dd/mm/yyyy' })
            //Datemask2 mm/dd/yyyy
            $('#datemask2').inputmask('mm/dd/yyyy', { 'placeholder': 'mm/dd/yyyy' })
            //Money Euro
            $('[data-mask]').inputmask()

            //Date range picker
            $('#reservation').daterangepicker()
            $('#periode').daterangepicker()
            //Date range picker with time picker
            $('#reservationtime').daterangepicker({ timePicker: true, timePickerIncrement: 30, format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A' })
            //Date range as a button
            $('#daterange-btn').daterangepicker(
                {
                    ranges: {
                        'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                        'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                        'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
                    },
                    startDate: moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
                    endDate: moment()
                },
                function (start, end) {
                    $('#daterange-btn span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'))
                }
            )
            //Date picker
            $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                autoclose: true
            })
            //Timepicker
            $('.timepicker').timepicker({
                showInputs: false
            })
        })
    </script>
...
```

And in Index.cshtml

```html
<!-- Date Range -->
            <div class="col-xs-3 ">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="reservation">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

However, the DickerPicker feature does not function and becomes the input text as shown below
[image]

What is the solution to being able to run one of the features that are on my web pages? thank you

Comment: Please check all references file you have include `');?` please remove this and check

Comment: Please change this one `~/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js');?>` to `~/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js`

Comment: You still have PHP closing tags in your link references. You would have to remove those tags and then run your program again.

Comment: remove that ');?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not linking the stylesheet and script properly and you should remove `');?>` from your link and script. This should solve the problem.

```
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/plugins/iCheck/square/blue.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">

    <!-- InputMask -->
    <script src="~/plugins/input-mask/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>
    <script src="~/plugins/input-mask/jquery.inputmask.date.extensions.js"></script>
    <script src="~/plugins/input-mask/jquery.inputmask.extensions.js"></script>
    <!-- date-range-picker -->
    <script src="~/bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <!-- bootstrap datepicker -->
    <script src="~/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```